# Maximum allowed number of run-time errors in Dymola

Tags: runtime-error, modelica, dymola

It might soud as an unorthodox question, but is there a way to increase the maximum allow number of run-time errors in a Dymola simulation ?

It concerns following error during run-time (due to a bug in Dymola), from which i know doesn't affect my results but which fails my simulation after *n*-errors:

```
ERROR: Failed to solve non-linear system using Newton solver.
To get more information: Turn on Simulation/Setup/Debug/Nonlinear solver diagnostics/Details
(...)
Solver will attempt to handle this problem.
```

Comment: If you know the value of `n` you could try to search for it in `DymolaDir/Source/*.h`

Comment: Well, i know *n* equals 50 though can't find this in any *.h or *.c